# Difficulty in database design

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

I am experiencing difficulty in MySQL database design.

I have the following tables:

```
school_table
id | school_name
---------------------------
1  | success primary school

stage_table
id | stage_name
---------------------------
1  | nursery
2  | primary
3  | secondary

school_stage_table
id | school_id | stage_id
---------------------------
1  |    1      |     1
2  |    1      |     2
```

school_stage_table is a linking table. This is because there is many to many relationship between school and stage, that is a single school may have many stages, and the same stage may have many schools.

**The problem comes here:**
Each stage has different attributes, and therefore different attribute values for different schools.

How do I model this scenario in a database? Need your help.

Comment: what kind of attributes you need for the stage? I think you need to provide more information about this.

Comment: You might have a school_stage_attributes table with (for instance) a school_stage_id (FK to school_satge_table.id) and the attributes associated with that stage for that school.

Comment: "different attributes"  is too vague. Can you be more specific? You may  have common attrs at `school_table` and create 3 specific tables with attrs sets for every `stage_table` row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option here would be to create a `stage_attribute` table containing at least the following *four* columns:

```
stage_attribute
id | school_id | stage_id | attribute
```

Each record in this table would correspond to a single attribute for a single stage, e.g.

```
1 | 1 | 1 | 'nap time'
2 | 1 | 1 | 'breakfast'
3 | 1 | 3 | 'phys ed'
```

I suspect that some of the difficulty in your mind was with the possibility of adding attribute columns to the `stage_table` for each attribute.  Of course, this is problematical because each stage could have different numbers or types of attributes, and it won't scale for many attributes.  The option I gave above eliminates many of these problems by using an arbitrary number of *records* to store the stage attribute information.

Comment: This doesn't seem quite right to me. Or, is perhaps only part of the answer.

Comment: Yes...I see this: `and therefore different attribute values for different schools` ... bad design?  By the way, Gordon Linoff is the best.  Actually, he might be a computer program at this point, having uploaded his SQL knowledge to a supercomputer.

Comment: I comment on his/its posts too ;-)

Answer (score 2):

As you previously said that you are having some issues that how to store different attributes of each stage of each schools.

Here you can take one table which will store all the attributes of each stage. You can use following table for storing attributes.

Table :

```
school_stage_attributes_table

id | school_stage_id | attributes_name  |  attributes_value
------------------------------------------------------------
1  |    1            |     attrib_1     |  value_1 
2  |    1            |     attrib_2     |  value_2
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use table school_stage_table for this different attribute values for different schools.

If You will use the same attributes schema for multiple schools, then there should be one more table called for example school_stage_options with fields

```
school_stage_options_id | stage_id | option1 | option2 ....
```

and later use `school_stage_options_id` in `school_stage_table` instead of using `stage_id`.